# Python Pandas Compare column

Tags: python, csv, pandas, multiple-columns

i need help to compare data from csv columns with another csv. To get the correct address

num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('example.csv'))  # count the number of lines

```
for row in range(num_line - 1):
    df1 = pd.read_csv("example.csv", na_values=['NA'])  # read csv addresses list that need to be fixed
    df2 = pd.read_csv("CTT.csv", na_values=['NA'])      # read csv with correct addresses 

    if cp7 == True:
```

compare column with another csv file

```
        if cp7 == 1:
```

cp7 matches with only one address

```
            File = open('Norm.csv', 'w')
            Norm = csv.writer(File)
            Norm = [column for column in Norm]
            File.close()
        else:
```

all cp7 possibilities

```
            File = open('PNorm.csv', 'w')
            PNorm = csv.writer(File)
            PNorm = [column for column in PNorm]
            File.close()

    elif cp4 == True:
```

all cp4 possibilities

compare column with another csv file

```
        File = open('PNorm.csv', 'w')
        PNorm = csv.writer(File)
        PNorm = [column for column in PNorm]
        File.close()
    else:
        pass

    if localidade == True:
```

all localidade possibilities

read localidade

```
        File = open('PNorm.csv', 'w')
        PNorm = csv.writer(File)
        PNorm = [column for column in PNorm]
        File.close()

    else:
        pass

    if tipovia == True 

        # compare column with another csv file

        if tipovia == 1:
```

TipoVia matches with only one address

```
            File = open('Norm.csv', 'w')
            Norm = csv.writer(File)
            Norm = [column for column in Norm]
            File.close()
        else:
```

all cp7 possibilities

```
            File = open('PNorm.csv', 'w')
            PNorm = csv.writer(File)
            PNorm = [column for column in PNorm]
            File.close()
    else:
        pass

    if nomerua_numpolicia == True
```

compare column with another csv file

```
        if nomerua_numpolicia == 1:
```

NomeRua_NumPolicia matches with only one address

```
            File = open('Norm.csv', 'w')
            Norm = csv.writer(File)
            Norm = [column for column in Norm]
            File.close()
        else:
```

all cp7 possibilities

```
            File = open('PNorm.csv', 'w')
            PNorm = csv.writer(File)
            PNorm = [column for column in PNorm]
            File.close()
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
if df1.reset_index(drop=True)["CP4"] == df2.reset_index(drop=True)["CP4"] and
df1.reset_index(drop=True)["CP3"] == df2.reset_index(drop=True)["CP3"]
```